# IntelliJ | Make Git Branches Widget stick to corners

Tags: multiple-monitors, intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm and various other JetBrains IDEs. Currently my Git Branches widget floats when I click to bring it up or use the shortcut `CTRL + SHIFT + ~`. My current monitor setup makes this more difficult where the floating widget is split between two monitors and also the bottom half is cut off.

Is there a way to make this a sticky widget where it is bound to the corner of the IDE?

Answer (score 1):

I use a third party program to do my GIT but I found that if you rightclick on the little icon in the extreme bottom left you can select "Version Control" as an option.

You can access this through View > Tool Windows > Version Control.

[image]

This then makes the version control accessible as a tab. I haven't tested this across projects.

Comment: What 3rd party program do you use?

Comment: I use [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) from Atlassian. It fits in nicely with our development ecosystem.